# How do I discriminate types on the fly with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have some json that looks like this:

```
[
  {"type":"child_obj_1", "message": "blah"},
  {"type":"child_obj_3", "apple": "red"},
  {"type":"child_obj_2", "banana": "fire!"},
  {"type":"doesnt_exist", "message": "blah"}
]
```

These correspond to types that look like this (the "doesnt_exist" type doesn't exist):

```
ParentObj
  -> ChildObj1
  -> ChildObj2
  -> ChildObj3
```

I want to be able to parse the json list into those types. The "doesnt_exist" type can fail silently. How do I do this using Jackson?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `@JsonTypeInfo` annotation from Jackson ? check its [documentation](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.9/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonTypeInfo.html) for more details.

Sample Usage:

```
 // Include Java class name ("com.myempl.ImplClass") as JSON property "class"
  @JsonTypeInfo(use=Id.CLASS, include=As.PROPERTY, property="class")

  // Include logical type name (defined in impl classes) as wrapper; 2 annotations
  @JsonTypeInfo(use=Id.NAME, include=As.WRAPPER_OBJECT)
  @JsonSubTypes({com.myemp.Impl1.class, com.myempl.Impl2.class})
```

Comment: I'am trying it but how do I :  // Include Java class name ("com.myempl.ImplClass") as JSON property "class"